# Ruby Kernel#autoload and Module#autoload difference

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `Kernel#autoload` and `Module#autoload`? What is the context in which each is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it might be seen in source code of these methods in standard documentation, [`Kernel#autoload`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload) calls [`Module#autoload`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-autoload) after casting the receiver to it’s class.

When one uses the most common approach and calls `autoload` on the class level:

```
class C
  autoload(:M, 'm')
end
```

the `Module#autoload` is called because `Class < Module`. Since the receiver is in this case already a `Class`’ instance, there is no necessity in explicit cast.

On the other hand, one might need to call `autoload` within a method body:

```
class C
  def c
    autoload(:M, 'm')
  end
end
```

In the latter case the receiver is an instance, and unless it’s a `Module` descendant, `Kernel#autoload` is called, which, in turn, retrieves the class of this instance and passes the call to it’s `Module#autoload`.